# Check if Chrome extension installed in unpacked mode

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to detect whether I'm running an extension that was installed from my .crx file or the extension was loaded as via 'Load unpacked extension...' button?

I'm aware about ID differences in that case, but I don't want to rely on hardcoded strings in the code.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If by "installed from my `.crx` file" you mean installed from Chrome Web Store you can simply check extension `manifest.json` for value of `update_url` attribute. CWS adds it when you upload your extension.

If you have a self-hosted `.crx` file, get your extension information using [`chrome.management.getSelf()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/management/#method-getSelf) and check `installType` of returned [ExtensionInfo](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/management/#type-ExtensionInfo) object. If it says `"development"` that means that extension was loaded unpacked in developer mode. `"normal"` means that it was installed from `.crx` file.

Comment: Chrome has since introduced `chrome.management.getSelf` that is much more appropriate for this purpose.

Comment: While this is technically the better solution, I don't like it because `chrome.management.getSelf` returns a promise, which is very annoying to deal with. Checking for `chrome.runtime.getManifest().update_url` is a lot more pleasant to work with.

Comment: Not only is the promise annoying to deal with but chrome.management is not available to content scripts which is where you would likely need to know "development" mode. But chrome.runtime.getManifest() is available to content scripts. However, I'm not sure if Edge add-ons store adds "update_url" to it.

Comment: update_url is not present in unpacked extensions for Manifest v3. Dennis' answer below details this.

Answer (score 29):

Here is a code sample how to do this:

```
function isDevMode() {
    return !('update_url' in chrome.runtime.getManifest());
}
```

or

```
const isProdMode = 'update_url' in chrome.runtime.getManifest()
```

Comment: A much simpler way is to use [chrome.runtime.getManifest()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getManifest) instead.

Comment: I first tried the other answer above involving `getSelf()` and `installType`. I needed to check this state in my injected content script as well, which didn't work as I can't access `chrome.management` there. This on the other hand is a solution that works elegantly, plus it's synchronous so I don't need to await each check!

Answer (score 6):

An extension is running in developer mode (i.e. unpacked), when it **does not** contain the `update_url` field in its [manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest).

This works because an unpacked extension's JSON manifest file should not contain the `update_url` field. This field is automatically added when [publishing via the Chrome Developer Dashboard](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate#H2-2).

For example, debug logs that only appear during development.

```
const IS_DEV_MODE = !('update_url' in chrome.runtime.getManifest());

function debugLog(str) {
  if (IS_DEV_MODE) console.log(str);
}

debugLog('This only appears in developer mode');
```

Comment: to save CPU time it's better to use `if (IS_DEV_MODE) console.log("YOUR_MSG");` everywhere

Comment: @user25 such refactoring falls into the micro optimisation category, usually at the cost of readability, and are almost never worth it. In fact, [running a benchmark shows that the suggestion is less performant](http://jsben.ch/TkUK1).

Comment: @Notflip it works wherever the [`chrome.runtime` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime) is available. I haven't tried it from a background script, but please give it a try and let us know.