# Use env variable in background script of Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to use an env variable in a background script of a Chrome extension?

I need to conditionally take an action depending on whether we are in development/production environment.

Comment: I am thinking that maybe if you are using an unpacked extension, then `chrome.runtime` might have some boolean information on it, telling you that you are in "development mode"?

Comment: Looks like we might have some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830649/check-if-chrome-extension-installed-in-unpacked-mode

Comment: In chrome such communication with the OS is done via native messaging (involving a custom executable). See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916511/read-environment-variable-from-google-chrome-extension

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read environment variable from Google Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916511/read-environment-variable-from-google-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 9):

You can get the [ExtensionInstallType](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#type-ExtensionInstallType) of a Chrome Extension which will be one of "admin", **"development"**, "normal", "sideload", or "other."

To do this, first add `"permissions": {"management"}` to `manifest.json` to enable [management](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-get).

Then in your `background.js` file, add the following code:

```
chrome.management.get(chrome.runtime.id, function (extensionInfo) {
      if (extensionInfo.installType === 'development') {
        // perform dev mode action here
      }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the `installType` without the need to add management permissions if you use the `.getSelf()` method ([documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/management/#method-getSelf)):

```
chrome.management.getSelf((self) => {
  console.log(self.installType)
})
```